# Cursor in a Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am getting the following error for the code

> ORA-06550: line 17, column 0: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

```
declare
    procedure empsindept (dep_no in emp.deptno%type) is
    totalnum number := 0;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ("The guys in dept are");
    for i in (select * from emp where deptno=dep_no) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.ename||"--------"||i.empno);
    totalnum:=totalnum+1;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line("The total guys are : "||totalnum);
end;
```

Please help me here

Thanks You

Comment: I would start with single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: Still the error with single qoutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `declare` you must complete the PL/SQL block, as stated [in the docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21plsql-242570.html):

> PL/SQL is a block-structured language. A PL/SQL block is defined by the keywords `DECLARE`, `BEGIN`, `EXCEPTION`, and `END`, which break up the block into three sections:
>
> - Declarative: statements that declare variables, constants, and other code elements, which can then be used within that block
> - Executable: statements that are run when the block is executed
> - Exception handling: a specially structured section you can use to “catch,” or trap, any exceptions that are raised when the executable section runs
>
> Only the executable section **is required**. You don’t have to declare anything in a block, and you don’t have to trap exceptions raised in that block.

So... your code should look like this, with an additional `begin ... end` at the end, in which you also will want to execute some statements, probably calling your procedure:

```
declare
    procedure empsindept (dep_no in emp.deptno%type) is
        totalnum number := 0;
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line ('The persons in dept ' || dep_no || ' are');
        for i in (select * from emp where deptno=dep_no) loop
            dbms_output.put_line(i.ename||'--------'||i.empno);
            totalnum:=totalnum+1;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line('The total number of persons is: '||totalnum);
    end;
begin
  -- something should happen here...
end;
```